# Software for assembling and illustrating scanned stencil pieces

Tags: software-recommendation

If I have separate stencil pieces (for example, separate branches to a tree) that I want to scan into my computer and then assemble the pieces and illustrate the final image (for example, assembling the tree on the computer and then coloring it in), which program should I use?

Comment: Are you going to redraw the tree or just create a composite/stitch  the photos together?

Comment: What applications do you have?

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what result you expect, but in general terms, if tou want a free program would be Gimp https://www.gimp.org There you can make some parts transparent, scale them to match other pices.

I can not give you a specific process because that would totally depend on your project.

The profesional solution would be Photoshop.